# jQuery sortable serialize multiple input fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable plugin and trying to update my database with AJAX but I can't pass the hidden input field values and getting "Undefined Index" error message.

Here is my script :

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');

        $.ajax({
            data: postData,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'save.php'
        });

    }
});
```

and here is my form:

```
<div id="sortable">

    <div id="city">
        <?php echo $city_name ?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="cityStatus[<?php echo $city_ID ?>]" value="1" <?php echo $checked ?>>    
        <input type="hidden" name="cityID[<?php echo $row->city_ID ?>]" value="<?php echo $city_ID ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="cityOrder[<?php echo $row->city_ID ?>]" value="<?php echo $city_order ?>">
    </div>

</div>
```

my save.php file:

```
foreach($_POST['cityStatus'] as $key => $value) {
    $cityID = $_POST['cityID'][$key];
    $cityStatus = $_POST['cityStatus'][$key];
    $cityOrder = $_POST['cityOrder'][$key];

    $updateCities = $db->execute(
        "UPDATE cities
        SET city_status=?, city_order=?
        WHERE city_ID=$cityID",
        array($cityStatus, $cityOrder));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling the JS how to send your POST parameters. Change your JS to:

```
data: { 'postData':postData }
```

This is the basically means `"postData="` + `postData` in key=value form. It tells the javascript and PHP that you want the variable `postData` to be linked to the key "postData", you will then be able to access it with `$_POST['postData']`

Comment: I am still getting Undefined index error. Could you please check out my updated code?

Comment: your trying to get values of keys which have not be defined in your 'data' section.. i.e. 'cityID' etc @curved